# Use GoCardless payments with Zapier

Tags: webhooks, zapier, gocardless

I'm trying to use Zapier to update Google Sheets with payment information from GoCardless. I can't see anything in the received event webhook that I can use to match a payment to a customer though.

```
events:
  1:
    id: EVTExxx8B
    created_at: 2021-03-29T21:57:38.658Z
    resource_type: payments
    action: confirmed
    links:
      payment: indxxx23
    details
      origin: gocardless
      cause: payment_confirmed
      bank_account_id: BA00xxx9N
      description: Enough time has passed since the payment was submitted for the banks to 
                   return an error, so this payment is now confirmed.

    metadata: 
meta:
  webhook_id: WB00xxxQTY
querystring:
```

I presume I need to match one of these IDs against the list of customers via the API but I'm a bit stuck on how to do this with Zapier. I can't find anything in the documentation to help (that I understand at least anyway). Has anyone managed to achieve anything similar please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer as I am not familiar with the details of Zapier, but this might point you in the right direction.

You can use the **`payment`** link (`events -> links -> payment`) to get the payment resource from their API, which will have a **`mandate`** link, which you might have saved somewhere. If not saved, you will need yet another query on the `mandate` which will give you the associated `customer`.